# How to install bcache on Linux 4.1?

Tags: bcache

The [official user documentation](http://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/Documentation/bcache.txt) doesn't bother to say a word about how `bcache` is structured and how it can be installed. There's no `.ko` file in the source root after building with `make`. I speculate it's part of the official kernel tree.

After setting `CONFIG_BCACHE=y` in `.config` in a custom build there's no `bcache.ko` kernel module in `/lib/modules/4.1-rc7/` and thus `bcache` doesn't work (or it's supposed to work without such module - how ever - and simply doesn't, but that's just speculation again).

I have the `bcache-tools` for userspace and manipulation of caches. Yet, I need a kernel module to make caching work.

Comment: You need `bcache-tools`. And you need to format your disk.

Comment: `bcache-tools` are for userspace, right? Caching won't work without a kernel modules which I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

From the [home page](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/#index2h1):

> Bcache has been merged into the mainline Linux kernel; for the latest stable bcache release use the latest 3.10 or 3.11 stable kernel.
>
> For the userspace tools,
>
> ```
> git clone <http://evilpiepirate.org/git/bcache-tools.git>
> ```

If you are using 3.11 or later, you already have bcache ([unless disabled on your distro build](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/md/bcache/Makefile)).

A `grep BCACHE /boot/config-$(uname -r)` should be enough to know if it's enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Bcache can be configured as a module or built into the kernel image. In the `.config` file, if you see `CONFIG_BCACHE=y`, it means that the feature is built into the kernel image. If you see `CONFIG_BCACHE=m`, it means that bcache is available as a module, so the compilation will produce a `.ko` file that needs to be loaded to use the feature. If you see `CONFIG_BCACHE=n` or no `CONFIG_BCACHE` at all, it means the feature is not compiled at all.

In your case, you have `CONFIG_BCACHE=y`, so the feature is included in the kernel image. There is no module file involved.

The documentation doesn't say anything about installation of the kernel code because there are no required installation steps besides enabling it in the kernel configuration, which you've done.

If the bcache feature doesn't work when you boot the kernel, that's a problem, but you didn't provide any information in your question that would help with that problem. Make sure that you've booted the right kernel. If you're sure of that, ask a new question, explaining what you did and what didn't work. Loading the feature doesn't do anything by itself, you need to configure a device with the userland tools and register it.

Comment: It seems like I fell for the slightly misleading description on https://github.com/g2p/bcache-tools/ which I suggested to fix in  https://github.com/g2p/bcache-tools/pull/27. And I just learned kernel build configuration...